# Illegal Value CryptoException when setting ECC Private Key S value in JavaCard

Tags: cryptography, javacard

I am getting an `CRYPTOEXCEPTION.ILLEGAL_VALUE` when attempting to set an `ECPrivateKey` with its `S,A,B,G,R,Field` values manually for a `SECP-256-R1` private key.

```
protected static byte[] EC_P256R1_FIELD_A = {
        (byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,
        (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,
        (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,
        (byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFC

    };
protected static byte[] EC_P256R1_FIELD_B = {
        (byte)0x5A,(byte)0xC6,(byte)0x35,(byte)0xD8,(byte)0xAA,(byte)0x3A,(byte)0x93,(byte)0xE7,
        (byte)0xB3,(byte)0xEB,(byte)0xBD,(byte)0x55,(byte)0x76,(byte)0x98,(byte)0x86,(byte)0xBC,
        (byte)0x65,(byte)0x1D,(byte)0x06,(byte)0xB0,(byte)0xCC,(byte)0x53,(byte)0xB0,(byte)0xF6,
        (byte)0x3B,(byte)0xCE,(byte)0x3C,(byte)0x3E,(byte)0x27,(byte)0xD2,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x4B

    };
protected static byte[] EC_P256R1_FIELD_G = {
        (byte)0x04,
        (byte)0x6B,(byte)0x17,(byte)0xD1,(byte)0xF2,(byte)0xE1,(byte)0x2C,(byte)0x42,(byte)0x47,
        (byte)0xF8,(byte)0xBC,(byte)0xE6,(byte)0xE5,(byte)0x63,(byte)0xA4,(byte)0x40,(byte)0xF2,
        (byte)0x77,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x7D,(byte)0x81,(byte)0x2D,(byte)0xEB,(byte)0x33,(byte)0xA0,
        (byte)0xF4,(byte)0xA1,(byte)0x39,(byte)0x45,(byte)0xD8,(byte)0x98,(byte)0xC2,(byte)0x96,
        (byte)0x4F,(byte)0xE3,(byte)0x42,(byte)0xE2,(byte)0xFE,(byte)0x1A,(byte)0x7F,(byte)0x9B,
        (byte)0x8E,(byte)0xE7,(byte)0xEB,(byte)0x4A,(byte)0x7C,(byte)0x0F,(byte)0x9E,(byte)0x16,
        (byte)0x2B,(byte)0xCE,(byte)0x33,(byte)0x57,(byte)0x6B,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x5E,(byte)0xCE,
        (byte)0xCB,(byte)0xB6,(byte)0x40,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x37,(byte)0xBF,(byte)0x51,(byte)0xF5

    };
protected static byte[] EC_P256R1_FIELD_R = {
        (byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,
        (byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,
        (byte)0xBC,(byte)0xE6,(byte)0xFA,(byte)0xAD,(byte)0xA7,(byte)0x17,(byte)0x9E,(byte)0x84,
        (byte)0xF3,(byte)0xB9,(byte)0xCA,(byte)0xC2,(byte)0xFC,(byte)0x63,(byte)0x25,(byte)0x51

    };
protected static byte[] EC_P256R1_FP = {
        (byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,
        (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,
        (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,
        (byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF

public void initSigner(byte[] input, short offset, short len) {
    ECPrivateKey tempKey = (ECPrivateKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_EC_FP_PRIVATE_TRANSIENT_RESET, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_EC_FP_256, false);
    tempKey.setS(input, offset, len);               
    tempKey.setA(EC_P256R1_FIELD_A, (short) 0, (short) EC_P256R1_FIELD_A.length);
    tempKey.setB(EC_P256R1_FIELD_B, (short) 0, (short) EC_P256R1_FIELD_B.length);
    tempKey.setG(EC_P256R1_FIELD_G, (short) 0, (short) EC_P256R1_FIELD_G.length);
    tempKey.setR(EC_P256R1_FIELD_R, (short) 0, (short) EC_P256R1_FIELD_R.length);  
    tempKey.setFieldFP(EC_P256R1_FP, (short) 0, (short) EC_P256R1_FP.length);
    Signature signer = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_ECDSA_SHA_256, true);
    signer.init(tempKey, Signature.MODE_SIGN);
}
```

Is there anything I am missing out when setting the ECC P256R1 values manually and how do I get the above code to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the particular card does not support `KeyBuilder.TYPE_EC_FP_PRIVATE_TRANSIENT_RESET` thus the reason why it kept throwing `CRYPTOEXCEPTION.ILLEGAL_VALUE`.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back! You should be able to accept your own answer by now. I've upvoted the answer, this is something that others can certainly benefit from. Sigh, you introduce new functionality and then they don't support it. It's a shame :|